# Get first row of CSV data in salesforce and use for mapping

Tags: batch, csv, parser, iteration

I want to get data from csv and upload it to salesforce.

I use this link http://www.blueengine.com.au/?p=40#comment-271 and http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/ to parse my data (they use batch process and iterator for this).

It is working fine but my problem is that I want to get the first row or the header of the csv and used its data for mapping.

I've tried to `System.debug` the data I get in the process but I can only get the last row and not the first one. How will can I get the first row instead?